# How to select gui language for opencv c++?

Tags: java, visual-c++, opencv, user-interface

i want to know which programming language i should use to make professional GUI to be compatible with opencv c++, **java or visual c++?**

thank you

Comment: Which you feel more comfortable with, go for that.

Comment: how can i connect between java gui and my opencv??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual C++ is the best option if you use openCV with C++ because you do all in the same way and in the same language.